# Comma separated value (1,2,3,4) or (1,false) always gives the last element in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I could not understand what javascript is doing for the below string.

```
console.log((1,2,3,4)); //print 4
console.log((1,false)); //print false
```

Don't know in which scenario i can use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that is what [the comma operator is defined as doing](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14). It evaluates as the RHS.

> The production Expression : Expression , AssignmentExpression is
>   evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating Expression.
> 2. Call GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.
> 4. Return GetValue(rref).

See also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

and

> You can use the comma operator when you want to include multiple expressions in a location that requires a single expression. The most common usage of this operator is to supply multiple parameters in a `for` loop.

There is no point in using it with immutable values on the LHS.